# How can I access my USB drive from my Windows Subsystem for Linux -- Ubuntu distribution?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I access my system's USB drive in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?  I'm using an Ubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's quite simple:

1. Create the mount point: `mkdir /mnt/g` *(add whatever word or letter you want, I used the matching letter to the windows drive. You might need to use `sudo` to create the directory in the `/mnt` directory.)*
2. Mount the drive to the directory using `sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g`

Answer (score 19):

Consider a slight alternative on the [currently accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116220/1165986):

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/<usb_drive_letter>
sudo mount -t drvfs <usb_drive_letter>: /mnt/<usb_drive_Letter> -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata
```

For a USB drive which is assigned in Windows to `H:`, for example:

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/h
sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/h -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata
```

In general, the accepted answer will work, but note that drives that are manually mounted this way do not follow the normal WSL automount settings.

Most *fixed* Windows drives will be mounted:

- In `/mnt/<drive_letter` for each drive.
- With the default WSL user and its primary group as the owner of the mount.
- A default umask/fmask/dmask of 000
- The `metadata` disabled for performance, which means only a "simplified permission" model will be used to map Windows/NTFS and Linux permissions.

However, USB drives that are manually mounted do not follow the [`[automount]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#automount-options) settings.

At the very least, you'll probably want your WSL user to be the owner, which is done with the `-o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER)` (usually, this is the same as -o uid=1000,gid=1000` in a default Ubuntu/WSL installation).

Adding in the `metadata` option can be useful if you want to preserve permissions via `rsync` or `cp -a`.

Comment: The owner options listed here are skipped on almost every other description I found. Although they weren't needed in a lot of instances they were needed in order for me to rsync data to my external drive without a load of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from NotTheDr01ds was very useful, although I did not find this to be the full answer.

Anyone feel free to edit the following with additional clarity and extra information, the following is a sequential list of tasks before I could copy to a WSL Distro with an attached storage device for running a backup.

#### Windows 10 host: ensure SSH Service is active

PowerShell (as Admin)...

```
Start-Service sshd

# Note the real Windows 10 username (only require after the forward-slash)
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

#### Source Linux/macOS host: test connectivity / login with the Windows 10 Local Account password

Remote Shell...

```
ssh Username@192.168.0.10
```

#### Windows 10 host: If requiring update/reset to local account password

PowerShell or Command Prompt...

```
# Use following in Command Prompt / PowerShell. Be aware this will require reboot and login with this password before Windows 10 PIN etc. will work again
net user Username PASSWORD_HERE
```

#### NOTE: rsync incompatibilities

The rsync binary may be too low on different Ubuntu distros which may cause unexpected errors from recent rsync development incompatibilities

#### NOTE: rsync unsupported features with Windows WSL

- use of '--crtimes' will result in errors such as.... rsync: The server does not support --crtimes (-N)
- use of '--fileflags' will result in errors such as.... rsync: on remote machine: --fileflags: unknown option
- use of '--xattrs' will result in errors such as.... rsync: [receiver] rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr("/mnt/h/path/.filename.txt.AB1de","user.com.apple.macl") failed: Operation not supported (95)

In addition, Windows WSL rsync is temperamental and may require the drive mounted with -o metadata to permit....

- use of --perms
- use of --times

#### Windows 10 host: If rsync incompatibility

May have to consider using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed for rsync 3.2.7+ package (at time of writing, not available with Ubuntu distros).

PowerShell...

```
wsl --install --distribution openSUSE-Tumbleweed
```

WSL Distro Shell...

```
# Example
zypper install rsync
```

#### Windows 10 WSL Distro: Mount the desired drive

To mount a drive to the WSL OS (e.g. an external disk drive), run the following from Admin user (e.g. user 1000); do NOT run this from root (e.g. user 0)

On reboot of Windows, this will likely reset the mount options to noatime.

WSL Distro Shell...

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/h
sudo mount -t drvfs H:\\ /mnt/h -o rw,relatime,dirsync,metadata,uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER)
exit
```

Then, to enable rsync to begin working the WSL Distro must be rebooted. Shutdown the WSL instance and start the instance again

PowerShell...

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl -d openSUSE-Tumbleweed
```

#### From the source Linux/macOS host: dry run test

Establish the sync works (use the Windows 10 Local Account password).

Remote shell...

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync \
--dry-run \
--rsync-path='wsl rsync' \
--recursive --perms --times --human-readable --itemize-changes --copy-links --progress \
--exclude '.DS_Store' \
/path/test \
Username@192.168.0.10:/mnt/h/test
```

#### From the source Linux/macOS host, real test

Establish the sync works to transfer the directories and files (use the Windows 10 Local Account password).

Remote shell...

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync \
--rsync-path='wsl rsync' \
--recursive --perms --times --human-readable --itemize-changes --copy-links --progress \
--exclude '.DS_Store' \
/path/test \
Username@192.168.0.10:/mnt/h/test
```

#### From the source Linux/macOS host, perform checksum double check

After sync works (use the Windows 10 Local Account password), establish all files were copied across correctly with checksum.

Remote shell...

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync \
--checksum \
--checksum-choice=md5 \
--rsync-path='wsl rsync' \
--recursive --perms --times --human-readable --itemize-changes --copy-links --progress \
--exclude '.DS_Store' \
/path/test \
Username@192.168.0.10:/mnt/h/test
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I'm thinking you probably meant to post this on a different question? This one doesn't have anything to do with `rsync` or `ssh` ;-)