# lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory

Tags: partitioning, usb, permissions, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to copy the files on my ubuntu home directory to a USB flash drive. I am following these guidelines [How to access a usb flash drive from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1). When I run `lsblk` I get `lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory`. When I run `sudo blkid` I get nothing. When I run `fdisk -l` I get  `fdisk: cannot open /proc/partitions: No such file or directory`.
When I run `cd media` and `ls` I get nothing. I also ran `lsusb`, and I got `unable to initialize libusb: -99`. Ran `usb-devices`, got nothing. Same with `dmesg | grep -i USB`.

Getting kinda desperate. Help would be much appreciated.

Update: I run `mkdir /mnt/c` and `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c` then `ls /mnt/c` and I got:

```
ls: cannot access 'DumpStack.log.tmp': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'hiberfil.sys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'pagefile.sys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'swapfile.sys': Permission denied
'$Recycle.Bin'             Intel                  ProgramData                  Users          hpswsetup
'$WinREAgent'              OneDriveTemp           Programas                    Windows        pagefile.sys
'Documents and Settings'   PerfLogs               Recovery                     adobeTemp      swapfile.sys
 DumpStack.log            'Program Files'        'System Volume Information'   hiberfil.sys
 DumpStack.log.tmp        'Program Files (x86)'   System.sav                   hp
```

I guess what I did was mounting the whole windows system to WSL. How do I access my flash drive now?

Comment: Is your "terminal" actually Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, its the ubuntu command line

Comment: Well yes... but actually no. The instructions you are trying to follow are only applicable to "real" Linux kernels that expose the `/proc` and `/sys` pseudo filesystems. For WSL, try this: [How can I access my USB drive from my Windows Subsystem for Linux -- Ubuntu distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116200/how-can-i-access-my-usb-drive-from-my-windows-subsystem-for-linux-ubuntu-dist)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you very much for your answer! I have run the two commands mentioned on that link. I run `sudo mount -t drvfs E: /mnt/g` instead of `sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g`, because that's my USB flash drive's "name". If I run the later option I get `mount: /mnt/g: special device G: does not exist.
<3>init: (160) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:673: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000` . What do I do now?

Comment: @steeldriver edited my question with more updtaes

Answer (score 1):

It sounds from the comments like you are close, but I'm going to repeat everything here to be clear.

- In Windows, identify the drive letter for your USB drive.  It sounds like that is `E:`, but just in case, we're going to call it `<drive_letter>:` (that's the letter, followed by a colon).
- In Windows, save an empty file from Notepad onto the USB drive so that we can confirm that it's correct later.  You can call this file `test.txt` or anything else.
- In Ubuntu in WSL:

  ```bash
  sudo mkdir /mnt/<drive_letter> # substitute your drive letter, with no colon
  # Don't worry if the above fails if the directory already exists

  sudo mount -t drvfs <drive_letter>: /mnt/<drive_Letter> -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata
  # the first time, use the colon, the second time, no colon.

  ls /mnt/<drive_letter>

  # Confirm that the file you saved from Notepad 
  # is in the drive.  This means that you've 
  # mounted it correctly.
  ```

  That mounts the drive with your user/group as the owner, and adds the `metadata` option so that WSL can store Linux permissions on NTFS drives.
- To copy over your user directory to that drive, you can use something like:

  ```
  sudo cp -axv ~ /mnt/<drive_letter>
  ```

  - `-a`:  Archive recursively, including permissions
  - `-x`:  Only copy files from the Ubuntu/WSL filesystem.  Prevents copying from other Windows drives if you happened to create a symlink somewhere in your home directory.
  - `-v`:  Verbose, so that you can see the filenames as they copy

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! It was so helpful. I managed to copy everything to my flash drive so easily. Can you please tell me how do I do to download it to another PC?